# Persistent UGC File Storage on AWS For Docker Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask, amazon-efs

I have a docker-based Flask app that I have been developing and it's nearing completion. I am currently moving to hosting it on AWS. The app allows users to generate various forms of content (usually image files) that are saved into a UGC folder within the /static folder of the app in my dev environment. This temporary solution worked fine in dev but it isn't going to suffice when ported to live as the static/ugc folder will be destroyed with each image update.

I therefore need an alternative solution and have been investigating EFS. Does anybody have experience with this service? Or in hosting persistent static files outside of a Docker app container in general and could advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look at using the [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) object storage service, via the [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) python client.

There's also a flask extension, [Flask-S3](https://flask-s3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which allows you to host general assets on S3 automatically. You'd probably need to code the logic for user-uploaded content yourself.