# Upload folder path for AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Python Flask app that seems to be otherwise working on the AWS Elastic Beanstalk platform. The one thing I can't figure out is where to save files that my web app allows users to upload. When run locally, I simply provide a path where the files are to be saved but once deployed to AWS EB, I am confused what I should change this path to. I assume I am missing something in this process and if someone could provide some guidance, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: [S3 is probably the missing piece](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59881143)

Comment: Ok, so how do I go about setting up S3 to then be able to upload files and serve them for my web app?

Comment: Ok, so my web app looks relatively similar to the app.py file shown towards the end of the first link you attached. I am just confused about what the UPLOAD_FOLDER would become in my app, since it is no longer local but running on the virtual environment? Is there some sort of reference to the AWS storage that  I am supposed to make?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Amazon S3 to store files with your Flask Application. Explore **Flask Boto3** Module. This module can be interface between your Flask Application and File Storage Service at Amazon.